# how to store xml value and count in array and display value in tableview cell in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

hi friend thank my data fetching from xml and result i can see in my console all element value i see in console but my problem in my NSLog(@"mDataArray count = %d",[mParserArray count]); 
i cannot see any count value in mdataarray
this is my parser code please cheek some one and tell me what the wrong i am doing in parser code

please cheek both class parser and controller class which i am create and help me friend
this is my parser.h file-----------------/

```
#import "TWeatherElement.h"//this is the class where the elements are Created
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface TWeatherParser : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate> 
{
    NSMutableArray *mParserArray;
    NSXMLParser *mXmlParser;
    NSMutableString *mCurrentElement;
    BOOL elementFound;
    TWeatherElement *mWeather;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *currentElement;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *mParserArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TWeatherElement *weatherobj;

-(void)getInitialiseWithData:(NSData *)inData;

@end



this is mu parser.mfile---------------------------/


#import "TWeatherParser.h"
#import "JourneyAppDelegate.h"
#import "api.h"
#import "TWeatherController.h"
//#define kParsingFinishedNotification @"ParsingFinishedNotification"


@implementation TWeatherParser
@synthesize weatherobj = mWeather;
@synthesize currentElement = mCurrentElement;
@synthesize mParserArray;

//-(id)init
//{
//  if ([super init]) 
//  {
//      currentElement release=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
//      mWeather =nil;
//
//  }
//  return self;
//}

-(void)getInitialiseWithData:(NSData *)inData
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:inData];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];   //YES if the receiver should report the namespace and qualified name of each element, NO otherwise. The default value is NO
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:YES]; //YES if the receiver should report the scope of namespace declarations, NO otherwise. The default value is NO.
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];//YES if the receiver should report declarations of external entities, NO otherwise. The default value is NO

    [parser parse];
    NSLog(@"%@",parser);

    [parser release];
}



-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString*) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"xml_api_reply"])
    {
        mWeather = [[TWeatherElement alloc]init];
        NSString *data8= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"version"];
        if(data8 !=nil)
            mWeather.xmlapireply =data8 ;
        [mParserArray addObject:data8];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"weather"])
    {
        NSString *data0= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"module_id"];
        if(data0 !=nil)
            mWeather.weather =data0 ;
        NSLog(@"weather==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"module_id"]);
    }
     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"current_date_time"])
     {
         NSString *data1= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
         if (data1 !=nil) 
             mWeather.currentdate =data1;
         NSLog(@"current_date_time==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
     }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"condition"])
            {
                NSString *data2= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data2 !=nil) 
                    mWeather.conditionname=data2;
                NSLog(@"condition==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);

            }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"humidity"])
            {
                NSString *data3= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data3 !=nil) 
                    mWeather.humidity =data3;
                NSLog(@"humidity==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);

            }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"icon "])
            {
                NSString *data4= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data4 !=nil) 
                    mWeather.icon =data4;
                NSLog(@"icon==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);

            }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"wind_condition "])
            {
                NSString *data5= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data5 !=nil) 
                    mWeather.wind =data5;
                NSLog(@"wind_condition==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
            }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"low "])
            {
                NSString *data6= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data6 !=nil) 
                    mWeather.mintemp = data6;
                NSLog(@"low==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
            }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"high "])
            {
                NSString *data7= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data7 !=nil) 
                    mWeather.maxtemp =data7;
                NSLog(@"high==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
            }
    //{
//      self.currentElement = [NSMutableString string];
//  }
//  else 
//  {
//      self.currentElement = nil;
//  }


}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString*)string
{
    if (nil!= self.currentElement)
    {
        [self.currentElement appendString:string];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qName
{
    if (nil != qName)
    {
        elementName  = qName;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"current_date_time "]) 
    {
        mWeather.currentdate = self.currentElement;

    }
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"condition "]) 
{
    mWeather.conditionname = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"humidity "]) 
{
    mWeather.humidity = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"icon "]) 
{
    mWeather.icon = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"wind_condition "]) 
{
    mWeather.wind = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"low "]) 
{
    mWeather.mintemp = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"high "]) 
{
    mWeather.maxtemp = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"weather"]) 
{
    [mParserArray addObject:mWeather];
    NSLog(@"mDataArray count = %d",[mParserArray count]);
    [mWeather release];

}   
}

//-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
//{
//  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ]postNotificationName:kParsingFinishedNotification object:mParserArray];
//}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    self.weatherobj = nil;
    self.currentElement = nil;
}
@end

and this is my controller class where i want to show all parser value in table view cell in iphone but it not working proper i think my code is not proper in controller class how i can show all data in controller class please help some one
this is TWeatherController.h-------------------------/

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TWeatherParser.h"
@class TWeatherParser;


@interface TWeatherController : UITableViewController {

    UITableView *mTableView;
    NSMutableArray *mImage;
    NSMutableArray *weatherarray;
    TWeatherParser *weather;




}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *mTableView;


@end


this is TWeatherController .m----------------------/

#import "TWeatherController.h"
#import "TWeatherCell.h"
#import "TWeatherElement.h"
#import "TWeatherParser.h"
#import "api.h"


@implementation TWeatherController
@synthesize mTableView;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
    }
    return self;
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

/*
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
*/


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    api *ap = [[api alloc]init];
    NSData *aData = [ap getBusXMLAtStop:@"1"];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:aData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //NSInteger value = [str intValue];
    if (str)
    {
        NSLog(@"this is success %@",ap.dataReply);
        TWeatherParser *parser = [[TWeatherParser alloc]init];
        [parser getInitialiseWithData:ap.dataReply];
        [parser release];


    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"cannot fetch" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertview show];
        [alertview release];
    }


    [ap release];



}

/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //TWeatherParser *parse = [[TWeatherParser alloc]init];
    //weatherarray = parse.mParserArray;
    return [weatherarray count];

}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


   TWeatherCell *cell =(TWeatherCell *) [mTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[TWeatherCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    TWeatherElement *newobj = [weather.mParserArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([newobj.icon isEqualToString:@"http://\n"])
    {
        cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listIcon-H.png"];
    }
    else {
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newobj.icon]];
        cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [imageData release];
    }
    cell.reportdate.text = newobj.currentdate;
    cell.conditionname.text = newobj.conditionname;
    cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",newobj.mintemp,newobj.maxtemp];
    cell.twodirection.text = newobj.wind;
    cell.humidity.text = newobj.humidity;
    //cell.reportdate.text = newobj.currentdate;


    //cell.reportdate.text =@"My journey";
//  cell.conditionname.text = @"raji";
//  cell.twotemp.text = @"pradeep"; 
//  cell.twodirection.text = @"harish";
//  cell.humidity.text =@"23";
//  cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listIcon-H.png"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    */
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    return 100.0;


}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"this is success %@",ap.dataReply);
        TWeatherParser *parser = [[TWeatherParser alloc]init];
        [parser getInitialiseWithData:ap.dataReply];
        [parser release];
```

Intialise your `mParserArray = [NSMutableArray array];`
Here you need to store the parsed array into some variable. You aren't doing it. From your code `weatherarray` is the variable which should hold the parsed values.
I hope this points you in right direction. Either make `self.weatherarray` point to `parser. mParserArray` or use what you had planned for.

Comment: i cant get u friend please explane

Comment: You are parsing correctly but you are not saving the result of the parsing operation into  your variable. Also check my edit